# C# Access resource from code

Tags: c#, wpf

In my solution i got a structure like this:

```
Solution
    +folder1
    +folder2
         projectXYZ   
         projectname
             +UserCustomizationDialog
                 +Resources
                    cur1.cur
```

I want to access the cur1.cur like this:

```
@"pack://application:,,,/projectname;component/UserCustomizationDialog/Resources/cur1.cur"
```

But I get an ArgumentException with additional information: Absolute Path information is required. The .cur file is a resource.
Does anybody know why?

Thank you very much

EDIT:
Please see the complete structure of my solution.

Comment: Have you set the Build Action to Resource?

Comment: yes it is a resource

Comment: have you set copy to output directory?

Comment: Please show how do you access resource overall, not only url string.

Comment: No, but this does not help.

Comment: @Shakra what do you mean?

Comment: The type seems to be an issue. When I add a .png in the same directory the by file name adjusted pack notation for that .png is correct. Any ideas?

Comment: Just want to see how you try to use this resource and where.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this way, Add the resource to Resources.resx from the path. 
And in code, you can access the resource by name like this.
object rm = Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetObject("TickMark");

TickMark is the png file I have added in the resources.

Hope this helps.