# Adjust custom cursor size

Tags: c#

I got a problem with .cur files.

I'm setting the cursor in a behavior of a window to some custom cursor:

```
 Mouse.OverrideCursor = (Cursor)mAssociatedObject.Resources["MoveCursor"];
```

In the window I got the cursor defined as a resource:

```
  <Cursor x:Key="MoveCursor">Resources/cur2.cur</Cursor>
```

This works fine.

Problem is if the user changes his cursor size in the windows settings, my cursor will still be of size 32x32.

Does anybody know a solution for this?

Thank you

Comment: Since you are asking a different question related to cursor files, is your previous one (http://stackoverflow.com/q/40841360/5265292) resolved?

Comment: @grek40 Yes it is. Seems as if the constructor of the `Cursor` class cant handle the pack notation. I added different cursors to the xaml file (in the resources)  ` <Cursor x:Key="NoCursor">Resources/NoCursor.cur</Cursor>` and access the cursor in the attached behavior like this `mAssociatedObject.Resources["NoCursor"]`.

Comment: You'll have to include more than one cursor resource.  Use SystemParameters.CursorHeight to discover the user's preference.

Comment: @HansPassant `SystemParameters.CursorHeight` return 32 pixels no matter what cursor theme I choose.

Answer (score 0):

As I understand your question has 2 parts:

1. how to know the cursor size defined in Windows Settings
2. drawing custom cursor as per the above size

For 1st part you can use [SystemParameters.CursorHeight](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.cursorheight(v=vs.110).aspx) as suggested by @Hans Passant.

And for second part you can refer the code below that uses [Cursor.DrawStretched()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.cursor.drawstretched(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is the sample code from MSDN:

```
private void DrawCursorsOnForm(Cursor cursor)
{
   // If the form's cursor is not the Hand cursor and the 
   // Current cursor is the Default, Draw the specified 
   // cursor on the form in normal size and twice normal size.
   if(this.Cursor != Cursors.Hand & 
     Cursor.Current == Cursors.Default)
   {
      // Draw the cursor stretched.
      Graphics graphics = this.CreateGraphics();
      Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle(
        new Point(10,10), new Size(cursor.Size.Width * 2, 
        cursor.Size.Height * 2)); // <<<<<<<<< you will need to define size based on SystemParameters.CursorHeight here
      cursor.DrawStretched(graphics, rectangle);

      // Dispose of the cursor.
      cursor.Dispose();
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. Is there something like a CursorHeightChanged event? I can check the Height at startup of course, but what if the user changes it while the program is running?

Comment: Not exactly CursorHeightChanged event but you will need to handle SystemParameters.StaticPropertyChanged event. @ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.staticpropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: CursorHeight is always 32 for me, no matter what cursor theme I activate.

Comment: I don't have an environment where I can try it out. My current work assignment is not on MS stack :(